# Creating OneIM DB with installer problems

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, failed-installation

I'm trying to installer oneim on my server , during the installation I get this error :

```
NAME = OneIM_mdb
   , FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Micrsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\OneIM.mdf'
   , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
   , FILEGROWTH = 10  %
 ) 
LOG ON (
   NAME = OneIM_ldb 
   , FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Micrsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\OneIM.ldf'
   , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
   , FILEGROWTH = 10  %
 ) 
Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Database error 1807: Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the operation later.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the operation later.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks to all for the attention

Comment: When you create a new database the schema and metadata gets copied from the `model` database - essentially cloning it. If that database is damaged or missing, or if the script is currently executing in the `model` database (or there's another session using it), an exclusive lock cannot be obtained and so the copy cannot be made.

Comment: Thank you so much , i resolved that , but it gave me another error , completely different :


Error during execution of statement: ALTER DATABASE OneIM ADD FILEGROUP OneIM_mem CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA
Database error 10794: The operation 'AUTO_CLOSE' is not supported with databases that have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup.
The operation 'AUTO_CLOSE' is not supported with databases that have a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup.